# On a continuous integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous integrable function such that $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)+f(x+1)>0$. Is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx >0$?

This problem came in tifr screening test -2012. The most I could infer is that if $f(x)\le0 ; \forall x \implies \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)+f(x+1)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-f(x+1)dx \ge0$ also from definition $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx\le 0$ if $f(x)\le0$. Thus $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=0$. If on a measure zero set the later condition happens then only I guess its correct. Isn't it?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the set where $f(x) < 0$, and split the integral into $4$ pieces. We have the translate $A + 1$, a set $B$ which is the complement of $A \cup (A + 1)$, and a correction:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx &= \int_A f(x) dx + \int_{A + 1} f(x) dx + \int_B f(x) dx - \int_{A \cap (A + 1)} f(x) dx
\end{align*}

The first two integrals combine as
$$\int_A f(x) + f(x + 1) dx > 0$$
since $f(x) + f(x + 1) > 0$ on $A$. (Assuming $A$ is nonempty, of course).

The third integral is nonnegative because we're off $A$. The final integral is at most zero since the integrand is non-positive. But we're subtracting it, so it's OK. A positive answer follows.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $A$ and $A+1$ are disjoint? It isn't the case when I take $A=[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Scientifica You're quite right in general. We have the condition $x \in A \implies f(x) + f(x + 1) > 0$; in particular, $f(x + 1) > 0$. Hence $x + 1$ is not in $A$, so $A$ is actually disjoint from its *left* translate $A - 1$. I had this reversed in my original answer, so I rewrote it. Thanks.

Comment: @user what happens when $A$ is not an interval. Say for example $A$ being the cantor set.

Comment: @user Thanks for answering me.

Comment: @user But why in particular $f(x+1)>0$? We can't say this because in fact $x\in A\implies f(x)<0$ and $A$ isn't necessary disjoint from its left translate. Never mind, your answer now is correct.